# mysql segregating rows according to column value, possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

This problem has been bugging me a lot since the past few days.
Here's what I thought of:
A super big retail store company has stores in many different cities, each store
was opened on a given day.
The table tabulating the data would have (atleast) two columns,
(1) city name (2) date opened
Output desirable: multiple lists, each list
containing all the stores of a given city ordered 
chronologically (by date opened) of 10 cities ordered
alphabetically.
To get around this I was thinking of:
Fetch #1: Alphabetically fetching 10 cities from the table
Fetch #2 (multiple fetches in a loop): Iterating each fetched city, and obtaining
all of its respective stores, making the order by date opened.

The above method which I've come up with does the job, however I was wondering if there
is a more concise way of doing it, which involves the looping though the stores of the cities while making fetch #1 itself, and thereby not increasing the time complexity by using an external loop and performing many sql executions instead of just one.
Would that be possible? one sql statement?

Comment: [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables).

Comment: @DCoder: The question only mentions one table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT city FROM my_table ORDER BY city LIMIT 10
) t ORDER BY city, opened
```

Split into separate lists when looping over the resultset within your application: just inspect `city` to see if it has changed since the last iteration.  In pseudocode:

```
for each record in resultset:
  if current city is not equal to last city then start new list
  output current record
  set last city to current city
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much eggyal. Just, about the limiting the number of cities alphabetically while making the fetch, do you know how to implement that into your current solution?

Comment: @Relfor: Which 10 cities do you want to choose?

Comment: ten cities which are alphabetically ahead in the table

Comment: @Relfor: One way would be to put `SELECT DISTINCT city FROM my_table ORDER BY city LIMIT 10` inside the parentheses above.

Comment: thanks, it works without any limit set in the sub query, however it gives an error when limit is supplied in there, apparently mysql doesn't permit that. Anyway, thanks a lot for the help!